# Where is Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssas, adomd.net

I'm trying to work through some examples working with Analysis Services Management Objects (AMO), specifically some of this content:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345093.aspx

These reference some objects in the Microsoft.AnalysisServices namespace which it says resides in the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll, but I can't find it in either the framework or extension references.  I found an unclear reference to `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Sql Server\<version>\sdk\assemblies` but it's not there either.

Can anyone direct me to where I can find this assembly and/or how to download/install it?

Comment: It should have a option when you installed SQL server, perhaps you had the box unchecked in the installer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies

This is from a 2014 developer install. If its not there you have to rerun setup and choose Analysis Services.

Answer (score 2):

You can also install it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/).

Run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
install-package Microsoft.AnalysisServices
```

Comment: There is a warning for this NuGet package - `The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.`

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server` seems like a newer option.